# Cross correlation R^2 value improvement

Tags: cross-correlation

I require some advice on achieving a better R^2 value using the cross correlation method. Is there any sort of way to improve an R^2 value to obtain better results? I have been looking at applying some sort of filter to every window before I calculate the R^2 value for that particular window, however, I am unsure if this is the correct method to use or if there there is a better way to achieve better results.

```
clc
clearvars
close all 

% signals
file_path1 = 'ref trigger new_000_ALL.csv';
file_path2 = 'meas trigger new_000_ALL.csv';

% Read the CSV file skipping the first 17 rows
ref = csvread(file_path1, 16, 0); 
meas = csvread(file_path2, 16, 0);

time_ref = ref(:,1);
signal_ref = ref(:,2);
dt = mean(diff(time_ref));
time_meas = meas(:,1);
signal_meas = meas(:,2);
Fs = 1/dt;

% Define valid common Time vector and interpolate data if needed (on new common Time vector) 
% (define which data has time delay and interpolate the other data on
% correct Time vector)
time_ref_min = time_ref(1);
time_meas_min = time_meas(1);
time_ref_max = time_ref(end);
time_meas_max = time_meas(end);

if time_ref_min>time_meas_min
    ind = time_ref<=time_meas_max;
    Time = time_ref(ind);
    signal_ref = signal_ref(ind);
    signal_meas = interp1(time_meas,signal_meas,Time);
else
    ind = time_meas<=time_ref_max;
    Time = time_meas(ind);
    signal_meas = signal_meas(ind);
    signal_ref = interp1(time_ref,signal_ref,Time);
end
clear time_ref time_meas

% FFT process
N = length(signal_ref);
Fs = 1/dt;
k=0:N-1;     %create a vector from 0 to N-1
T=N/Fs;      %get the frequency interval
Freq=k/T;    %create the frequency range

FFT_ref = fft(signal_ref); % make up for the lack of 1/N in Matlab FFT
FFT_meas = fft(signal_meas);% make up for the lack of 1/N in Matlab FFT

%only want the first half of the FFT, since it is redundant
cutOff = ceil(N/2); 
Freq = Freq(1:cutOff);
FFT_ref = FFT_ref(1:cutOff);
FFT_meas = FFT_meas(1:cutOff);

FFT_n = length(FFT_meas);
window_size = 240; % Amount of data point used to separate data chunks.
overlap_percentage = 50; % Desired overlap percentage
overlap = window_size * overlap_percentage / 100;
shift = window_size-overlap;    % nb of samples between 2 contiguous buffers  
% Calculate number of windows
num_windows = fix((FFT_n-window_size)/shift +1);
corr_values = cell(num_windows, 1);
lags_values = cell(num_windows, 1);

% Iterate over the signal with sliding window
for ci = 1:num_windows
    % Define start and end indices for the current window
    start_index = 1+(ci-1)*shift;
    end_index = min(start_index+ window_size-1,FFT_n);
    
    % Extract the current window
    window_ref = FFT_ref(start_index:end_index);
    window_meas = FFT_meas(start_index:end_index);
    ifft_ref = ifft(window_ref);
    ifft_meas = ifft(window_meas);
    
   [corr_temp, lags_temp] = xcorr(ifft_ref, ifft_meas, 'coeff');
    
    corr_values{ci} = corr_temp;
    lags_values{ci} = lags_temp;
    
end
% Concatenate all correlation and lags values
corr = cell2mat(corr_values');
lags = cell2mat(lags_values);
lag = lags(1,:);

figure(1)
plot(Time, signal_ref,Time, signal_meas);
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Voltage (V)');
title('Time signals')
legend('Reference signal','Measured signal')

figure(2)
m_corr = mean(abs(corr),2);
plot(lag, m_corr);
hold on
xlabel('Cross correlation shift (GHz)')
ylabel('Amplitude (A.U.')
xlim([-20 20])

% FWHM computation (dx of points at 50% of the peak value)
[ZxP,ZxN] = find_zc(lag, m_corr,max(m_corr)/2);
FWHM = ZxN - ZxP;
plot([ZxP  ZxN], ones(2,1)*max(m_corr)/2,'r');
hold off

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function [ZxP,ZxN] = find_zc(x,y,threshold)

% put data in rows
x = x(:);
y = y(:);

% positive slope "zero" crossing detection, using linear interpolation
y = y - threshold;
zci = @(data) find(diff(sign(data))>0);  %define function: returns indices of +ZCs
ix=zci(y);                      %find indices of + zero crossings of x
ZeroX = @(x0,y0,x1,y1) x0 - (y0.*(x0 - x1))./(y0 - y1); % Interpolated x value for Zero-Crossing 
ZxP = ZeroX(x(ix),y(ix),x(ix+1),y(ix+1));

% negative slope "zero" crossing detection, using linear interpolation
zci = @(data) find(diff(sign(data))<0);  %define function: returns indices of +ZCs
ix=zci(y);                      %find indices of + zero crossings of x
ZeroX = @(x0,y0,x1,y1) x0 - (y0.*(x0 - x1))./(y0 - y1); % Interpolated x value for Zero-Crossing 
ZxN = ZeroX(x(ix),y(ix),x(ix+1),y(ix+1));

end
```

[image: Time series signals]

[image: R^2 mean value]

I have tried different window sizes, to no avail. Is it because the sizes of the ifft_ref and ifft_meas might not be scaled properly?